# Unable to add the values of the same array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have a following data that contains a array. What I want to do is add the visitor_cv values together if 
the visitor_day, the visitor_id, and the type is the same . If you see the following code below it's like array 6 & 13 has the same data and the 23 and 36 has the same data as well. I want simply add the values of the visitor_cs to have 2. But I have no idea how I will be able to do that logic. I would love to hear from you!

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => mail
            [visitor_id] => 4
            [visitor_day] => 20180516
            [visitor_cv] => 1
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [type] => mail
            [visitor_id] => 4
            [visitor_day] => 20180516
            [visitor_cv] => 1
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [type] => skype
            [visitor_id] => 4
            [visitor_day] => 20180516
            [visitor_cv] => 1
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [type] => skype
            [visitor_id] => 4
            [visitor_day] => 20180516
            [visitor_cv] => 1
        )
```

I want the above result to be like

```
 Array
(
    [type] => mail
    [visitor_id] => 4
    [visitor_day] => 20180516
    [visitor_cv] => 2
)


 Array
(
    [type] => skype
    [visitor_id] => 4
    [visitor_day] => 20180516
    [visitor_cv] => 2
)
```

Comment: What is the source of your data? for example if database, you may be able to "Group By". If you're not sure I'd suggest starting with simple for/foreach loops and manually sorting and adding into a final array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option to do this could be to create an array key based on the `type`, `visitor_id` and `visitor_day` and then sum the `visitor_cv`:

```
$items = [
    ["type" => "mail", "visitor_id" => 4 ,"visitor_day" => 20180516, "visitor_cv" => 1],
    ["type" => "mail", "visitor_id" => 4, "visitor_day" => 20180516, "visitor_cv" => 1],
    ["type" => "skype", "visitor_id" => 4, "visitor_day" => 20180516,"visitor_cv" => 1],
    ["type" => "skype", "visitor_id" => 4, "visitor_day" => 20180516, "visitor_cv" => 1]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $key = $item["type"] . $item["visitor_id"] . $item["visitor_day"];
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        $result[$key] = $item;
        continue;
    }
    $result[$key]["visitor_cv"] += $item["visitor_cv"];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aeRp3)

Answer (score 0):

I created this function it takes an array of arrays and the keys you want to check on as an array also,
then it creates a value by concatenating the keys values and put them in an array to check later if it exists or not, if it exists so skip else it put the value in the result array called tempArray, then return it as the result

```
function arrayUnique($array, $keys) { 
    $tempArray = []; 
    $keyArray = []; 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        $keysValue = '';
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $keysValue .= $val[$key];
        }

        if(!in_array($keysValue, $keyArray)) {
            $keyArray[] = $keysValue;
            $tempArray[] = $val;
        }
    } 

    return $tempArray; 
} 


$a = [
    ['name' => 'hassan', 'age' => 2, 'test' => 1],
    ['name' => 'hassan', 'age' => 1, 'test' => 1],
    ['name' => 'ali', 'age' => 2, 'test' => 1]
];
var_dump(arrayUnique($a, ['age', 'test']));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UhB1t)